# Distrust versus mistrust

Tags: vocabulary

Is there any difference between **distrust** and **mistrust**, even if very subtle? Can they be used interchangeably in all contexts? Which one is more common? Dictionaries seem to define them as synonyms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two are indeed near-perfect synonyms in most cases. Most people would infer little from choosing one over the other, although you could perhaps argue that distrust has a slightly stronger connotation than mistrust. Mistrust may connote a general lack of trust, for example with someone you don't know. Distrust may connote a more active lack of trust, for example with someone who has lied to you in the past. The shades of meaning are subtle, however, and either would be appropriate in most cases. According to Google ngrams, as well as my own experience, "distrust" is used about twice as often as "mistrust".

Comment: I thought that distrust is not trusting some one or thing, but mistrust is mistakenly placing trust in some one or thing that proved to be untrustworthy.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree the shades of meaning are subtle. In words that can take both mis- and dis- prefixes, dis- is often the more deliberate and better-informed version (misplace vs. displace, misuse vs. disuse), so I agree there can be a sense of "mistake" in mistrust in addition to just "missing". I don't think that mistrust is necessarily a feeling that can only be felt retrospectively, however, which would be the case if it required subsequent discovery that the trust was, in fact, misplaced. One can mistrust without trusting in the first place, or without evidence of untrustworthiness.

Comment: Anecdotally, I agree - you might mistrust a stranger who seems suspicious, but you would distrust someone who has betrayed you in the past. Practically speaking, I keep someone I mistrust at arm's length, and someone I distrust probably a bit further...

Answer (score 8):

Regardless of whether it's [a noun...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sense%20of%20mistrust%2Csense%20of%20distrust&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

...or [a verb...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20mistrust%20him%2CI%20distrust%20him&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10)

[image]

...both words are about equally common. But "common" is a *relative* term, as shown by [this chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20distrust%20him%2CI%20mistrust%20him%2CI%20do%20not%20trust%20him&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10)

[image]

---

The [***mis-***](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=mis-) (bad, wrong) and [***dis-***](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dis-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) (lack, opposite, apart) prefixes clearly lead to different meanings in, say, ***misplace, displace***, but that hasn't happened with ***mistrust, distrust***.

Personally, I think both the noun and verb usages of ***mistrust / distrust*** are as near to synonyms as anything in English. Except that ***mistrust*** is a little more "antiquated", as implied by [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20mistrust%2CI%20distrust&year_start=1660&year_end=1860&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=30) for three centuries ago.

For *learners*, it might be more important to note that explicit negation of ***trust*** *(You **can't** trust him, There's a **lack** of trust)* is much more natural in most contexts than the "morphologically" negated forms.

---

In for a penny, in for a pound. [Here's the long view,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mistrust%20him%2Cdistrust%20him%2Cdo%20not%20trust%20him&year_start=1650&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=30) showing how the explicitly negated verb form has displaced the morphologically negated forms over the course of several centuries.

[image]

Comment: There's no reason to default to male pronouns in the search (and such defaulting is a sign of our unconscious gender biases that we should oppose).

Comment: No reason??? What about the fact that [***do not trust him*** is five times more common than ***do not trust her***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+not+trust+him%2Cdo+not+trust+her&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) in Google Books? That wasn't "unconscious gender bias" on my part - I made the choice I did because that gave me better access to the available data.